# How do you know when writing a program that it will have a certain TIME or SPACE complexity?

Tags: performance, optimization, memory, logic, runtime

Are there certain things that you do in your code where you think "yeah, this will be adding a lot to the runtime of the program..." or "yeah, this will be adding a lot to the memory usage of the program..."

How do you know? It is a feel? practice?

I understanding the more loops generally means the more runtime. But what else do you feel out for in terms of understanding the speed and time your code will take?

Thanks

Comment: You can calculate your run time with `Big O Notation`, thats the basic understanding and theory of how long stuff takes. It also depends on the language itself. In C++ for example code takes much longer to execute when you use copy instead of references.  Memory is similar. don't repeat unnecessary stuff (make it static in functions for example) and don't make `class`es longer than they need to be. It comes down to the knowledge of the language, Big O and a lot of practice to get the feel for the runtime, without much thinking.